# Отобразить изображение из потока

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Сервер в ответ на запрос, отвечает файлом превью.

Пытаюсь эту превью показать в контейнере `Grid`

```
ImageSource img;
        
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    var stream1 = new MemoryStream(response.GetResponseStream().ReadByte());
    img = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
}
var image1 = new Image { Source = img, Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill };
        
gridImages.Children.Add(image1, 0, 0);

Content = gridImages;
```

В результате ничего не отображает, хотя в ответе от сервера изображение есть.

Если указать ссылку на прямую, то показывает без проблем.

```
var image1 = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("картинка")), Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill };
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать через `HttpClient`

```
var response = client.GetAsync(new Uri(url)).Result;

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    ImageSource img = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream.Result);

    var image1 = new Image { Source = img, Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill };
    gridImages.Children.Add(image1, 0, 0);
    Content = gridImages;
}
```